# MonoDroid Java Bindings: UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, binding, xamarin.android

In my MonoDroid Java Bindings Project I'm also using a native lib (somelib.so), which is included as "AndroidNativeLibrary"

The library seems to be loaded successfully:

```
"...
Trying to load lib /data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/app_dynlibs/somelib.so
Added shared lib /data/data/AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1/app_dynlibs/somelib.so
```

But when the first method of a class from this lib gets called, an error occurs:

Exception Ljava/lang/**UnsatisfiedLinkError**; thrown while initializing Lcom/abc/def/someclass/   Unhandled Exception:

What are the common causes for such errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my,  a simple "Clean" and "Rebuild" did it...

Found at

http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-UnsatisfiedLinkError-Library-monodroid-not-found-td4620040.html